# Save documents one per one and save their _id's to array Mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose, async-await

I am trying to save some documents from an array. I need to save them one per one, and getting theirs ids, for then use it for another transaction. My problem is with the async flow, I think. Because when I print the array is empty but in the database all documents were inserted.

I am using graphql and mongoose.

```
const saveSubTask= async (tasks) => {
  let taskIds = [];

  for (const task of tasks) {
    const taskModel = await getModel(task.type)
    const response = await taskModel.create(task)
      response.then( (doc) => {
        console.dir(doc) // {_id : ObjectId("324sd33..."), description: "sdf....", ...}
        inputIds.push({_id: doc._id})
      })
  }
  return taskIds;
}

export const resolvers = {
 ....
 Mutation: {
    inputCreate: async (_, { task }) => {
      const response = await saveSubTask(task.subTask);
      console.dir(response) // response = []
      return await {}
    },
  },
...
}
```

When I call the saveSubTask function I receive a empty array.

I use getModel() for getting the model that I need, because I have something like a factory, because I use different models for save in then save collection in MongoDB. For this, I just going to put a brief of the model code, for only focus on principal structure of the model.

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";
const { ObjectId } = Schema.Types;

const TaskSchemaBase = Schema({
  description: String,
  type: {type: String, enum: ['Event', 'Note']},
  enable: Boolean,
  subTaks: [
    {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'taskBase'}
  ]
}, {collection: 'tasks', discriminatorKey: 'kind'} );

export const TaskBase = mongoose.model("taskBase", TaskSchemaBase);
```

Which is the correct way to do that. I need to send every document splitted.

My model is this :

Comment: What's `inputIds` in your code?

Comment: It is an array where I am going to save all just inserted documents. The function saveSubTask should return that array for using then.